# Selenium-Webdriver 2.33.0 Gets Stuck, Won't Open Browser(Using jruby)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jruby

Hello I am running on a Windows 7 HP Slim machine using jruby 1.7.4 with the options set to 1.8 Ruby. We are behind a proxy here at work.

I was using Selenium 2.18.0 and decided to upgrade my version of selenium-webdriver to 2.33.0.

When I try to open a new browser the execution just gets stuck at this snippet of code in the capabilities.rb file of the gem

```
`self.proxy    = opts.delete(:proxy)`
```

inside of this initialize method

```
def initialize(opts = {})
  @capabilities = DEFAULTS.merge(opts)
  self.proxy    = opts.delete(:proxy)
end
```

Sometimes it seems to get stuck before it executes that bit of code, but I haven't seen it get past that point.

The tests just keep trying to run and open a browser, but as far as I can tell it never stops and no browser opens. A friend of mine was having the same issue and they let it run for 20 minutes and it still didn't error out.

The same thing happens whether you are trying to use firefox, ie, or chrome.

I kept going backwards in versions of the gems. It seems this issue starts happening to me when I get to Selenium-Webdriver 2.22.0 but before that it opens a browser just fine for me.

I have a friend using a lenovo laptop with Windows xp, jruby 1.7.4, and ruby option set to 1.8 also behind the proxy that doesn't seem to get this problem when they updated their gems. The browser opens just fine for them. We've been struggling to figure out why this is happening and would appreciate any help we can get as I have been unable to find anything online regarding this issue.

Thanks!